# what is wrong with this sql query that used order by and left join together? Is this the right way to do it?

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join, sql-order-by, where-clause

```
SELECT ts.contact_id as contact_id,  ts.contact_name as name ,  ts.is_contact_active  as is_active, ts.created_at,ts.updated_at 
FROM tb_summary ts 
ORDER by created_at 
LEFT JOIN  (tcs.contact_address as address FROM tb_contacts tcs)  ON tcs.contact_id = ts.contact_id
WHERE ts.business_owner_id = ? AND ts.is_contact_active = ?
```

This query throws

> ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LEFT JOIN  tcs.Contact_address as address, tcs.Contact_id FROM tb_Contacts tcs  ' at line 2

Comment: Order by should be after the joins

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Pause work on the overall goal, chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is way off. A query takes only one `from` clause, that may contain multiple `join`s. And the `order by` clause goes at the end.

So:

```
SELECT 
    ts.contact_id as contact_id,  
    ts.contact_name as name,  
    ts.is_contact_active as is_active, 
    ts.created_at,ts.updated_at, 
    tc.contact_address as address
FROM tb_summary ts 
LEFT JOIN tb_contacts tc ON tc.contact_id = ts.contact_id 
WHERE ts.business_owner_id = ? AND ts.is_contact_active = ?
ORDER by ts.created_at
```

Answer (score 0):

A `SELECT` statement consists of a sequence of clauses.  Your query has four clauses:

- `SELECT`
- `FROM`
- `WHERE`
- `ORDER BY`

These operators must be in this order.

`JOIN` is an *operator* in the `FROM` clause.   So, it should be structure more like this:

```
SELECT ts.contact_id as contact_id,  ts.contact_name as name,  ts.is_contact_active  as is_active, ts.created_at, ts.updated_at
FROM tb_summary ts LEFT JOIN 
     tcs.contact_address address tca
     ON tca.contact_id = ts.contact_id
WHERE ts.business_owner_id = ? AND ts.is_contact_active = ?  
ORDER by created_at
```

From what I can tell, the query is still non-sensical.  The `contact_address` table is not being used.